# Reactive or non-reactive parameter passing in WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've been reading a lot about WebFlux lately and sources use Reactor differently, both ways seem to work.

What is the difference between a controller (or a Spring Data Reactive Repository) method accepting `String` / `Mono<String>`? Is there any performance impact? Do I need to pass everything back and forth wrapped in Reactive types or it doesn't matter?

An example from an official Spring tutorial:

```
@PostMapping("/people")
Flux<People> namesByLastname(@RequestBody Flux<Person> people) {
    return template.insertAll(people);
}
```

However, something like this also works (of course template has to accept non-reactive people here, this modification is ad-hoc):

```
@PostMapping("/people")
Flux<People> namesByLastname(@RequestBody List<Person> people) {
    return template.insertAll(people);
}
```

Comment: I am asking this myself too. I actually think that Spring can benefit from reactive handler parameters because it build the pipe rather than perform mapping immediately.

However, I think that this just does not cause any performance impact at all.